# SBT Packaging shows unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, scala, rest, sbt

I am writing a scala class which does a rest call to upload a zip file. I am using SBT to create a jar out of this class. 'sbt package' command gives me a jar. I have added all the dependency jars(httpcore-4.3,httpclient-4.5.1,httpmime-4.5.1) in the lib folder. sbt run works fine and i am getting the correct output. but when i run the jar I am getting the following exception.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ContentBody
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at restTesting.main(restTesting.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:71)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:139)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:71)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:139)
at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.run(ObjectRunner.scala:28)
at scala.tools.nsc.JarRunner$.run(MainGenericRunner.scala:16)
at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:35)
at scala.tools.nsc.JarRunner$.runJar(MainGenericRunner.scala:28)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:78)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:96)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:105)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

This is my Scala class

`

```
import java.io.File
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.{HttpMultipartMode, MultipartEntityBuilder}
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder

object restTesting {
  def restTest(fileName:String):Unit =
  {
    val url = "http://ip:port"
    val post = new HttpPost(url)
    post.addHeader("Content-Type","application/zip")
    post.addHeader("zipFileName","zipdemocode2")

    val bin = new FileBody(new File(fileName))
    val reqentity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
    reqentity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
    reqentity.addPart("bin",bin)

    val entity = reqentity.build()
    post.setEntity(entity)

    val client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
    val response = client.execute(post)
    val resentity = response.getEntity
    println(resentity.getContent.read())
  }

  def main(args:Array[String])
  {
    restTest("path to zip file")
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking is a fat jar which includes all of dependencies. 
You can use [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) to export single fat jar.

Otherwise you should add each jar to classpath.

Comment: You can also use [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) for this, which has different tradeoffs.